# Order Statistics: Expected order statistic of a distribution given an order statistic of a linearly dependent distribution.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, order-statistics

say I have $X \sim \texttt{Binomial}(n, p)$ and $Y \sim \texttt{Binomial}(cn, p)$ where $0 \leq c \leq 1$. Also, I know what $E[W_{X_1}], E[W_{X_2}, ...]$ where $W_{X_i}$ is the $i$th largest sample. I was wondering if there was a straight forward way to get
$E[W_{Y_i}]$ where $W_{Y_i}$ is the $i$th largest sample of $Y$?

Comment: I assume $\frac{1}{c}$ divides $n$, otherwise $cn$ wouldn't be a whole number, right?

Comment: @DanielP yep, exactly. It may be more like round($cn$) but for now, I think it is fine to assume that $cn$ is a whole number.

Comment: I doubt it is straightforward.

Comment: As an example, suppose your sample sizes were $4$ and $X\sim \text{Bin}(4,\frac12)$ and $Y \sim \text{Bin}(2,\frac12)$, I see no obvious way to get from $E[X_{(1)}]\approx 1.01$, $E[X_{(2)}]\approx 1.70$,  $E[X_{(3)}]\approx 2.30$,  $E[X_{(4)}]\approx 2.99$ to $E[Y_{(1)}]\approx 0.32$, $E[Y_{(2)}]\approx 0.79$,  $E[Y_{(3)}]\approx 1.21$,  $E[Y_{(4)}]\approx 1.69$

Comment: Yeah @Henry, I was struggling here as well. I could also do with a loose-ish lower bound though. If I had a lower bound on the expectation, that would work. For now I can get a lower bound of something like $E[W_{Y_i}] \geq E[W_{X_i}] - (1- c) \cdot n$. But, this is not good enough and seems to be too strong.